# What do these as3 codes mean?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action

Can somebody explain for me about these as3 code

```
var _loc_2:* = new ByteArray();
_loc_2.writeByte(67);
_loc_2.writeByte(87);
_loc_2.writeByte(83);
param1.position = 21;
param1.readBytes(_loc_2, 124, param1.bytesAvailable - 121);
param1.readBytes(_loc_2, 3);
param1.readBytes(_loc_2);
return _loc_2;
```

I need you to explain for me about 2 command:  `param1.readBytes(_loc_2,3)` and  `param1.readBytes(_loc_2)`, what do they mean? and how do these code work?

Answer (score 1):

This is obfuscated code.  This looks like you are trying to read the Actionscript from a decompiled Flash movie, so it's deliberately hard to read.

Your code doesn't show the type of param1, but looking at the code it's probably a FileStream or ByteArray

The code

```
param1.readBytes(_loc_2,3)
```

is reading the all bytes after the fourth byte from _loc2 and storing in param1, whatever that is

Comment: It's not necessarily true that this is a Socket. It's ByteArray for sure.
And what the code does is that reads some data from some ByteArray.

Comment: Yes, param1 could be a Socket, a ByteArray, a FileStream, probably some other objects too :) - we need to see the definition...

Comment: Actually I don't think param1 can be a Socket as it sets position which doesn't exist in Socket... Updated my answer